# File data storing

Tags: android

i did an application to collects light sensor data, such that these data are stored in text file in the external sdcard, the data is stored correctly and file are created successfully but the problem is when then application running on the my device for x period (e.g 1 min)the data is stored but when is close the application and re running  it on from the device  for the same period also the new collected data are append stored to the previous stored data from previous running and i noted that when the sizes of the text files is increases with each running.
 i need for each running ,the collected data is stored totally (for the whole period of the running i.e 1 min ) in the text file and when i re- running the application again the new collected data of the new running to be overwriting on previous stored data.

i attempted to do that using arraylist, i .e when then app starts running i put all gathered reading in array list and when the running is stopped the arraylist will out all gathered data  to the text file but when i re-running app the array list also gathered data and append out it into the text file next to the previous running stored data, where this is the problem which need to solve,i need to overwrite new running gathered data on the previous running stored data.

the code of collecting light sensor data looks like:

```
    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        if(event.sensor.getType()==Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT){
            max =  msensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_LIGHT).getMaximumRange();
            //getMaximumRange() is the maximum range of the sensor in the sensor's unit.
            //tv1.setText("Max Reading: " + String.valueOf(max));
            tv1.setText(msg +"Max Reading: " + String.valueOf(max) );
            tv1.invalidate();
            lightMeter.setMax((int)max);
            //setMax is the max  of the upper range of this progress bar 
            currentReading = event.values[0];
            //timestamp = event.timestamp;
            lightMeter.setProgress((int)currentReading);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Event Happend '", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            tv2.setText("Current Reading: " + String.valueOf(currentReading));
            current_reading_list.add((double) currentReading);


        }
```

the code of writing from array list into file looks like :

```
public void writing_in_file_1(){


    try{
        fw  = new FileWriter(file_1, true);
        bw  = new BufferedWriter(fw);
        out = new PrintWriter(bw);
        //out.append( String.valueOf(currentReading + " \t"));
        //out.append(String.valueOf(current_reading_list));
        out.print(String.valueOf(current_reading_list));
        out.flush();

        Toast.makeText(this,"Done writing SD 'specific text file'", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    catch   (IOException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{
        try {
            bw.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

the writing is done when the stop button is pressed:

```
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.bt1:
        counter_function();
        //onResume();
        break;

    case R.id.bt2:
        onPause();
        writing_in_file_1();


        tv1.setText("");
        tv2.setText("");
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }



}
```

can any one help me?

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the constructor [FileWriter(File file, boolean append)](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/FileWriter.html#FileWriter%28java.io.File,%20boolean%29) with append = true

Replace

```
fw  = new FileWriter(file_1, true);
```

with

```
fw  = new FileWriter(file_1, false);
```